# Large tech allowed on Intl. flight?

Tags: air-travel, cellphones, airport-security, security

I have a 16000mAh power bank that I use to charge my phone and iPad. I was concerned of it size being a problem for Canadian-USA border security.

Is this actually a problem or will they not even care? I know this may seem like a dumb question.

Comment: That depends on the airline, the airport , the terminal ,the security personal.. all of which have a say and all can authorize or negate .. Too many variables to have an exact and correct answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I travel between Ireland and the USA about five times a year, I carry with me in carry-on luggage:

- A 17" laptop
- An iPad
- An Android tablet
- Two or three mobile phones
- Cables for the above
- A USB power block
- A small power bank (not 16000mAh, though)

And I've never had a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that's sound almost like what I'm bringing :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean one of those USB batteries?  They're not much bigger than an iPhone so no, no problem at all.

However, you should not check batteries.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just wondering, why not check them?

Comment: Lithium batteries have had some incidents of spontaneous combustion.  It is much easier to handle this in the cabin vs the hold.